# Outbound Message and Error Respose

Tags: error-messages, workflowoutboundmessage, session-id

I wanted to process the outbound message error response back in Salesforce.

Based on my research, it is not possible as per the [Ideas Community](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaview?id=08730000000Bpv4AAC.)

I tried to test outbound message using a [PutsReq](https://putsreq.com/). I understand that we can send a session ID in the outbound message. Will it be possible to leverage session ID to configure a response back to salesforce about the error message in case of Outbound Message failure?

I am looking for a working code that I can try out in my developer edition.

Thanks

Comment: This is supported and [documented here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_om_outboundmessaging_understanding.htm) and there is [Trailhead that shows how to do this](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/modules/salesforce_heroku_integration/callouts_workflow_with_heroku)

Comment: @cropredy, thanks for pointing me in the right direction!